# make sure input has only 5 characters

Tags: jquery, validation

Been searching for a way to make sure a specific input (zipcode) has only 5 characters (no more or less). I found one solution here that was written in JS, but i need one in Jquery

i have this so far, but does not seem to work, any help would be great. thanks in advance -- Dave

//HTML

```
<input name="propzip" type="text" required="required" id="propZip" maxlength="5" placeholder="Property Zip*" />
```

//SCRIPT

```
var numbers = /^\d{5}$/;  

$('#propZip').blur(function(){

if ($('#propZip').val().length===numbers){

                alert('field ok');

            } else {
                alert('Please check zipcode.');
            }
});
```

Comment: jQuery _is_ Javascript - can you clarify what precisely you need?

Comment: you use numbers as a pattern. Simple change the value of `numbers` to 5, not a pattern.

Comment: @lolka_bolka  Maybe he wants to verify that the input has exactly *five numerics digits* ?

Comment: @VitorLima You are right. I've added it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use your pattern as regular expression. You've looking for the function `match`

```
    var pattern = /^\d{5}$/;

    $('#propZip').blur(function() {
        if ($('#propZip').val().match(pattern)) {
            alert('field ok');
        } else {
            alert('Please check zipcode.');
        }
    });
```

Comment: this worked great for my situation, thanks for the help. i knew i needed the .match() just wasn't sure where it went in code

Answer (score 0):

Just change the variable numbers to 5

`numbers = 5`

If your input is inside a form and you want check it before submit, you can simple use HTML5 instead of javascript, doing something like

```
 <input name="propzip" type="text" required="required" pattern=".{5}" 
    id="propZip" placeholder="Property Zip*" title="Please, check the zipCode" />
```

Comment: Just FYI, using `===` is faster than `==`. So your last point shouldn't be in your answer (IMO).

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon  I didn't know it. I'll search for it. But, anyway, I edited the answer and removed this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
Something like this=?
```

//HTML

```
    <input type="text" name="" id="propZip" >
<input type="button" name="" id="btn" value="click me">
```

//JQuery

```
        <script>
        $(function(){
            $("#btn").click(function(){
                {
                if($("#propZip").val().length > 5) {
                    alert("to long!")
                }else{
                    alert("gooooood size!");
                }
            }
            })

        });
    </script>
```